# Can photo frames be automatically detected on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, vision

I am designing a photo editing application. Is it possible to automatically import the x, y, width, height values of these album frames into the application, when the user adds the photo album frame from the photos application? So can we automatically detect photo frames?. Because I will add the feature of adding photos to the frame by putting the plus(+) button in these frames. I need rects of all frames for now.

I share frames that can be an example:

[image: example1]
[image: example2]
[image: example3]

I wrote code to find rectangular and transparent area, but it is not enough to find their position. Now, I'm sharing them:

```
func isAnyPixelTransparent(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        return false // UIImage could not be converted to CGImage
    }
    
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    
    // Create a buffer to hold pixel data
    let pixelData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: width * height * 4)
    
    // Create a context to extract pixel data
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    guard let context = CGContext(data: pixelData,
                                  width: width,
                                  height: height,
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: width * 4,
                                  space: colorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue) else {
        return false // CGContext could not be created
    }
    
    // Draw the image into the context
    context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    
    // Loop through pixel data to check transparency
    var isAnyPixelTransparent = false
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: width * height * 4, by: 4) {
        if pixelData[i + 3] == 0 {
            isAnyPixelTransparent = true
            break
        }
    }
    
    // Clean up
    pixelData.deallocate()
    
    return isAnyPixelTransparent
}

func detectRectangles(in image: UIImage) -> Bool {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        print("Could not get CGImage from the provided image.")
        return false
    }
    
    var rectanglesDetected = false
    
    let request = VNDetectRectanglesRequest { request, error in
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRectangleObservation] else {
            print("No rectangle observations found.")
            return
        }
        
        for observation in observations {
            let rect = observation.boundingBox
            print("Detected rectangle at \(rect)")
            rectanglesDetected = true
        }
    }
    
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
    
    do {
        try handler.perform([request])
    } catch {
        print("Error performing rectangle detection: \(error)")
        rectanglesDetected = false
    }
    
    return rectanglesDetected
}
```

Comment: You *could* use `VNRectangleObservation` ... but you'll run into some problems. For example, we can get this result from your 3rd image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWBe2.png ... but this from your 2nd image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmdtB.png ... as you see, 3 overlapping rects (red, green, blue). I can show you what needs to change in your code if you could work with that, but... You'd be much better off saving out **each frame** as its own image -- or, include the *rects to use* in a data set for each multi-frame image.